# UIButton not firing touchesbegan

Tags: ios, uibutton

I have a bunch of regular UIButtons, with a target when pressed. But I also want it to work when swiped, and activate touchesbegan or touchesmoved/touchesended. I need it because I want create something like a swipable word puzzle, which will also receive touchup presses. But the  swipe series only works if the touches begins on self.view , but not on the button themselves. It will just be pressed and no touch events are registered.

```
UIButton* Butt = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
Butt.frame= CGRectMake(0, -500, 63 , 63);
[Butt addTarget:self action:@selector(clickWord:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
Butt.userInteractionEnabled= YES;
[aSubview addSubview:Butt];
```

Can anyone help? I know that putting the UIButtons in the subview might be troublesome, but I really wish to do that to keep the elements in a structured way, and not everything is directly on self.view.

I tried to subclass the buttons but it didn't help

Subclassing code:

```
- (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
  [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
  [self.nextResponder touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
  // This is where the touch is passed on
 }

 - (void) toouchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
  [super touchesMoved:touches withEvent:event];
  [self.nextResponder touchesMoved:touches withEvent:event];
 // This is where the touch is passed on
}

- (void) touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
  [super touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];
  [self.nextResponder touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];
  // This is where the touch is passed on
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like touch are responding but when it gets to the rect of uibutton, they will be intercepted.

Answer (score 1):

If you're programming a game, maybe it would be worth it to use a framework like [Cocos2D](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/) instead of the standard UI Elements?

But back to topic: If you create a screensized invisible UIView on top of your buttons to check for swipes and, if it's no swipe, switch "user interaction enabled" to off, maybe it works?

Otherwise create a matrix where you check where the user touched and what he did on this view and use this data in the background. Then you would also need no buttons anymore...

Hope it helps a bit.

Edit: It feels odd to modify the standard UI Elements in a way where they don't do anything close to what they're developed for. Maybe subclassing UIControl itself will be what you want? It won't be very easy, but probably the solution which works best for you?